# Probability of a transient first hitting time in a continuous-time Markov chain that already has an absorbing state using matrix exponential

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Introduction:**

Consider that we have a finite-state continuous-time Markov chain $\{X(t):t \geq 0\}$ where $X(t) = 1,2,\dots,N$ such that $X(t) = N$ is an absorbing state. This continuous-time Markov chain (CTMC) can thus be considered to model a phase-type distribution. Furthermore, it has an initial distribution given by $\vec{p} \in \mathbf{\Delta}^{N-1}$ with the constraint that $p_N = 0$ such that it cannot immediately start in the absorbing state. Here, $\mathbf{\Delta}^{N-1}$ is understood to be the probability simplex over $N-1$ degrees of freedom. The generator matrix $\mathbf{Q} \in \mathbb{R}$ is not assumed to have any structure, although I will mainly be using upper triangular generator matrices such that the phase-type distribution is acyclic.

For each state $X(t)=x = 1,2,\dots,N-1$ I would like to get a distribution $\vec{\varphi}(t) \in \mathbf{\Delta}^{N-2}$ where $\varphi_i(t)$ denotes the probability that the system has just entered state $i$ at time $t$ for the first time. I understand this to be a *first-passage time event* which we will denote as $f_{i,t} = \{ X(t)=i \}\cup\{X(\tau)\neq i: 0 \leq t \leq t^{-}\}$ and the event that the state $i$ has not been entered as $f_{i,t}' = \{X(\tau)\neq i: 0 \leq t \leq t\}$.

Most are familiar with the *transient occupation probability distribution*:
$$
\vec{\pi}(t) = \vec{p} e^{\mathbf{Q}t}
$$
where it has been assumed that we are dealing with row vectors. If one gains evidence at time $t$ that an event has not been triggered due to the absorbing phase not being occupied then one obtains a filtered distribution through normalising each of the transient (non-absorbing) states $i = 1,2,\dots,N-1$:
$$
\pi^*_i(t) = \frac{\pi_i(t)}{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \pi_j(t)}.
$$
Now we have covered a familiar theory. However, occupation probabilities are different from the probabilities of a first-passage event $f_{i,t}$ as denoted by $\varphi_i(t)$. I would like to compute these probabilities using the matrix exponential in a manner similar to occupation probabilities (assuming this can actually be done). Here is my progress. I ask to please be corrected and guided where necessary.

**Attempt: (EDIT: incorrect approach)**

So I consider doing the following for each transient state $i=1,2,\dots,N-1$. First, make state $i$ an absorbing state through making the $i^{th}$ row in $\mathbf{Q}$ a row of zeros to create $\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}$. Now $\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}$ has two absorbing states; it seems important to keep the original. We then compute the following vector
$$
\vec{u}^{(i)}(t) = \vec{p} e^{\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}t}
$$
and keep only the $i^{th}$ entry $u^{(i)}_i(t)$. We now have $[u^{(i)}_i(t):i=1,2,\dots,N-1]$. This is not a valid probability distribution as $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}u^{(i)}_i(t) \neq 1$. Intuitively, one would normalise this to obtain $\varphi_i(t)$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,N-1$:
$$
\varphi_i(t) = \frac{u^{(i)}_i(t)}{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}u^{(j)}_j(t)}.
$$
The meaning of normalisation would be to include evidence that one of the transient states has been hit for the first time.

As you can see, my attempt basically just copies that of filtered transient occupation probabilities where I have considered a first passage time to be a phase-type distribution. I do not completely trust my approach.

**EDIT: correct approach**

When in doubt, turn to simulations. The simulations can then be used as a reference to whether one's guess at the mathematics is correct. The figure below shows the simulations and the result of the correct approach which will be explained in what follows. I have also included the Python code such that the results can be reproduced. Everything was done in a rush so do please do excuse the fact that the code is not efficient or optimised.

[image: First passage time probabilities]

So let $\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}$ instead denote the original generator matrix that has the $i^{th}$ row and column deleted. Moreover, $\vec{p}^{(i)}$ is the original row vector with the $i^{th}$ entry removed. This probability distribution is not renormalised. Lastly, let $\vec{r}^{(i)}$ be the $i^{th}$ column of $\mathbf{Q}$ such that its $i^{th}$ entry is removed. This is essentially the resultant column that was removed from $\mathbf{Q}$ to produce $\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}$. This is a column vector. What we have done, is to obtain the necessary components as to describe the following sub-density function:
$$
g(t,i) = \vec{p}^{(i)} e^{\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}t}\vec{r}^{(i)}.
$$
This is a sub-density as $\int_{0}^\infty g(t,i) \leq 1$. This is because it is part of a competing risk scenario with two risks: the original absorbing state and the new one $i$. Hence, $g(t,i)$ assigns probability mass to the first hitting/passage time taking place in $[t,t+\Delta t]$ where $\Delta t$ is very small such that state $i$ is hit and not the original absorbing state. A different perspective is to think of any state other than $i$ being occupied at time $t^{-}$ and then jumping to $X(t)=i$. Indeed, $\vec{p}^{(i)} e^{\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}t}$ describes the probabilities that any other transient state is occupied at time $t$. The latter part (the instantaneous transition to $i$) is described by hazard rates. These hazard rates are constant as they are given by an exponential distribution and are found in $\vec{r}^{(i)}$. These two events produce the probability density as given above.

The correct probability of the first passage to state $i$ as time $t$ is given as
$$
\varphi_i(t) = \frac{g(t,i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} g(t,i)}.
$$
The normalisation can be interpreted as conditioning on "or" statements: either state $i$ is hit for the first time or state $1$ or state $2$ or ... or state $N-1$. Hence, we condition on the fact that the absorbing state has not been hit either.

**Last edit/conclusion:**
Before closing this question, I would like to remark on the following observations.

Firstly, I was quite lucky that using the probability density functions $g(t,i)$ worked. Strictly speaking, this is not correct. These denoted the joint probability that phase $i$ has never been hit up to time $t$ and is then hit in the interval $[t,t+\Delta t)$ where $\Delta t$ is infinitesimally small. However, we need to condition on the fact that the absorbing state was never hit otherwise the process would not be able to proceed and hit phase $i$. Note that $\vec{p}^{(i)} e^{\mathbf{Q}^{(i)}t}$ gives the probabilities of occupying phase $j\neq i$ at time $t$. By virtue of the system being in phase $j$, it cannot be in the absorbing phase. Hence, this can be regarded as the probability that system occupies phase $j=i$ at time $t$ and not the absorbing phase. Phrasing it like this allows for the conditional probability to be obtained as we now need to divide through by the probaility that the absorbing phase was never entered. This is the survival function of a phase-type distribution. If $t^*$ denotes the time of absorbption then $P(t^* > t) = \bar{G}(t) = \vec{p} e^{\mathbf{Q}t} \mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is an appropriate length column vector of ones intended to perform summation. We thus have the following conditional distribution that likely does not integrate to one over its domain/support:
$$
g(t,i|t^*>t) = \frac{g(t,i)}{\bar{G}(t)}.
$$
Nonetheless, $\varphi_i(t)$ remains unchanged in peforming normalisation as $\bar{G}(t)$ cancels out. That is where the luck came in.

Secondly, the probability of a first hitting time is non-neglible or non-zero only if one conditions in a first hitting time taking place at time $t$. This is exactly what was done in the in the computation of $\varphi_i(t)$:
$$
\varphi_i(t) = \frac{g(t,i)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} g(t,i)}.
$$
This is because we have restricted the event space to a space that takes up a very small portion in time. In other words, in continuous-time where the system produces a piece-wise constant trajectory one can expect transitions (which are instantaneous jumps) to take up zero mass of the interval $[0,t]$. This interval has all its mass allocated to phase/states being occupied (the piecewise constant part). I though this was an interesting apsect of the problem. Of course, one can condition on a transition occuring as opposed to a fist hitting time (first transition into a state). This would just scale the probabilities differently.

**Code (Python)**

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.linalg import expm
# This class creates a random phase-type distribution.
# It also allows one to sample a trajectory until observing an absorption event.
# The state hit during this trajectory (an when) are recorded in 
# self.first_hitting_count.
# This allows for self.filtered_fht_probs to be obtained which
# are the empirial first hitting/passage probabilities.
class RandomPhaseType(object):
    
    def __init__(self,N,time_grid,
                     rate_range=(0,3)):
        self.N = N
        self.time_grid = time_grid
        self.states = np.arange(self.N,dtype=int)
        self.transient_states = self.states[:-1]
        self.absorbing_state = self.N-1
        self.Nt = len(self.time_grid)
        self.rate_range = rate_range      
        self.get_generator()
        self.get_initial_probs()
        self.uniformisation()
        self.absorb(N-1)  # last phase is always absorbing
        self.first_hitting_count = np.zeros((self.Nt,self.N))
        
    def get_generator(self):
        Q = np.random.uniform(self.rate_range[0],
                              self.rate_range[1],
                              (self.N,self.N))
        for i in range(N):
            Q[i,i] = 0
            Q[i,i] = - Q[i].sum()
        self.Q = Q
        self.Qsub = self.Q[:-1,:-1] # for phase-type distribtution
        return None

    def get_initial_probs(self):
        self.p = np.concatenate((np.random.dirichlet([1]*(self.N-1)),[0]))
        self.psub = self.p[:-1] # for phase-type distribtution
        return None
    
    def absorb(self,idx):
        assert 0 <= idx <= self.N -1 
        # Make this an absorbing state
        self.Q[idx] = 0
        return None
    
    def uniformisation(self):
        self.P = self.Q.copy()  # embedded chain
        self.rates = -np.diagonal(self.Q)
        for x in range(self.N-1):
            row = self.Q[x]/self.rates[x]
            row[x] = 0
            self.P[x] = row
        self.P[-1,-1] = 1
        self.Psub = self.P[:-1,:-1]
        return None
    
    def get_ph(self):
        r = self.Q[:-1,-1]
        return self.psub,self.Qsub,r
    
    def rvs(self):
        # Helper function for self.sample
        seen = set()
        t = 0
        x = np.random.choice(self.transient_states,p=self.psub)
        self.first_hitting_count[0,x] += 1
        seen.add(x)
        while True:
            delta = np.random.exponential(scale=1/self.rates[x])
            t += delta
            x = np.random.choice(self.states,p=self.P[x])
            if x not in seen:
                bin_idx = np.digitize(t,self.time_grid) - 1
                self.first_hitting_count[bin_idx,x] += 1
                seen.add(x)
            if x == self.absorbing_state:
                break
        return t
    
    def sample(self,nsamples,verbose=True):
        if verbose:
            report = tqdm
        else:
            report = lambda x:x
        out = np.array([self.rvs() for _ in report(range(nsamples))])
        self.fht = self.first_hitting_count
        self.fht_probs = np.nan_to_num(self.fht/self.fht.sum(axis=1,keepdims=True))
        self.filtered_fht_probs = np.nan_to_num(self.fht[:,:-1]/self.fht[:,:-1].sum(
                                                                axis=1,keepdims=True))
        return out
    

def get_subph_pdf(p,Q,idx):
    # Get a single sub-density
    N = len(p)
    assert 0 <= idx <= N-1
    psub = np.delete(p,idx)
    # psub = psub/psub.sum() # do not normalise
    Qsub = np.delete(Q,idx,0) # row delete
    rsub = Qsub[:,idx]
    Qsub = np.delete(Qsub,idx,1)  # column delete
    return lambda t: psub @ expm(Qsub*t) @ rsub # sub-density
    
def get_sub_pdfs(p,Q):
    # Get all sub-density functions
    N = len(p)
    pdfs = np.zeros(N,dtype=object)
    for n in range(N):
        pdfs[n] = get_subph_pdf(p,Q,n)
    def sub_pdfs(t):
        return np.array([pdf(t) for pdf in pdfs])
    return sub_pdfs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    N = 5
    Nt = 90
    np.random.seed(69)
    time_grid = np.linspace(0,5,Nt) # used to bin empirical first hitting time counts
    ph = RandomPhaseType(N,time_grid)
    t = ph.sample(5000000)
    fht = ph.fht
    fht_probs = ph.fht_probs
    filtered_fht_probs = ph.filtered_fht_probs # empirical 
    p,Q,r = ph.get_ph()
    pdfs = get_sub_pdfs(p,Q)                  # theoretical
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
    plt.step(time_grid,filtered_fht_probs,where='post')
    P = np.zeros((Nt,N-1))
    for idx,t in tqdm(enumerate(time_grid)):
        row = pdfs(t)
        P[idx] = row/row.sum()  # important normalisation
    plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None) # reset color cycle as to match first plots
    plt.plot(time_grid,P)
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('First passage probabilities')
    plt.title('Empirical vs theoretical first passage probabilities')
```

Comment: is the question still open? what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I should probably close it. I have my answer. If an alternative exists then that would be great. It seems a bit dodgy to be normalising a vector of probability density functions.